# How can I get MOXy to assign a parent when unmarshalling a child with an XmlInverseReference?

Tags: jpa, jboss, jaxb, jackson, moxy

My setup:

JBoss AS 7.1.1 using JPA, Hibernate (to connect to PostgreSQL), RESTEasy, Jackson 1.9.2 for JSON, EclipseLink MOXy 2.4.1 for XML

I have two entities - **Group** and **User**.  A group contains many users (one-to-many). I'm declaring a bi-directional relationship with JPA annotations (see below), so I have to prevent cycles by using `@JsonManagedReference`/`@JsonBackReference` (for JSON) and `@XmlInverseReference` (for XML).  This works as expected, except when I try to create a user via REST, I can't assign her to a group when using XML.  When using JSON, it works:

Jackson JSON **works** (successfully adds Jane Doe and places her in group 5):

```
POST request to /user
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Body: {"name":"Jane Doe", "group":{"id":5}}

Response:

{
   "id": 12,
   "name":"Jane Doe"
}

Hibernate: insert into users (group_id, name, id) values (5, 'Jane Doe', 12)
```

Here's the GroupEndpoint response after adding a user with Jackson:

```
GET request to /group
Accept: application/json

Response:

[{"id":5,"name":"My User Group","users":[{"id":12,"name":"Jane Doe"}]}
```

MOXy XML **doesn't work** (Jane Doe is orphaned):

```
POST request to /user
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
Body: <name>Jane Doe</name><group><id>5</id></group>

Response:

    <user><name>Jane Doe</name><id>12</id></user>

Hibernate: insert into users (group_id, name, id) values (null, 'Jane Doe', 12)
```

Here's the GroupEndpoint response after adding a user with MOXy:

```
GET request to /group
Accept: application/xml

Response:

<collection>
  <group><id>5</id><name>My User Group</name></group>
</collection>
```

I've tried `@XmlID` and `@XmlIDREF`, same issue.  `@XmlTransient` will similarly ignore the child-to-parent relationship on both marshal and unmarshal.

My question:

How can I add a User to a Group via the User REST endpoint without MOXy ignoring the new user's group field (marked as @XmlInverseReference)?

Should I augment my REST endpoints, create an XmlAdapter, or write a custom serializer? Am I missing an easy solution with different annotations?  *Is there an entirely different approach to exposing relational objects via REST that is preferred?*  Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the group entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Group implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="group", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference("group-user")
    private Set<User> users;

    // Omitting getters and setters etc...
}
```

Here's the user entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference("group-user")
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="users")
    private Group group;

    // Omitting getters and setters etc...
}
```

Here's the User REST endpoint:

```
@Stateful
@Path("/user")
@TransactionAttribute
public class UserEndpoint {
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/xml","application/json"})
    public User create(User entity) {
        em.joinTransaction();
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Here's the Group REST endpoint (included to show the need to prevent cycles):

```
@Stateful
@Path("/group")
@TransactionAttribute
public class GroupEndpoint {
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
    public List<Group> listAll() {
        final List<Group> results = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM Group x").getResultList();
        return results;
    }
}
```

Here's the GroupEndpoint **MOXy** response after adding a user with **Jackson**, to test for cycles:

```
GET request to /group
Accept: application/xml

Response:

<collection>
  <group>
     <id>5</id>
     <name>My User Group</name>
     <users><id>12</id><name>Jane Doe</name></users>
  </group>
</collection>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Support for your use case has now been implemented in EclipseLink 2.5.0.  You can download a nightly label (staring March 1st, 2013) from the following link.

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

**JAVA MODEL**

Now MOXy supports specifying the `@XmlInverseReference` annotation on both directions of a relationship.  When specified alone it is treated just like `@XmlTransient` is for marshalling, and to make it writeable you need to use it in combination with `@XmlElement`.

**User**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    //@JsonBackReference("group-user")
    @XmlElement
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="users")
    private Group group;

    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    // Omitting other getters and setters etc...
}
```

**Group**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Group implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="group", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    //@JsonManagedReference("group-user")
    @XmlElement
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="group")
    private Set<User> users;

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    // Omitting other getters and setters etc...
}
```

**DEMO CODE**

**Demo**

Below is some code that can be run to prove that everything works.  In addition to the XML use case, MOXy could also be used to handle the JSON.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.UnmarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        // XML USE CASE
        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<user><name>Jane Doe</name><group><id>5</id></group></user>");
        User userFromXML = (User) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
        System.out.println(userFromXML.getGroup().getUsers());

        // JSON USE CASE
        StringReader json = new StringReader("{\"name\":\"Jane Doe\", \"group\":{\"id\":5}}");
        unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        unmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        StreamSource jsonSource = new StreamSource(json);
        User userFromJSON = unmarshaller.unmarshal(jsonSource, User.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(userFromJSON.getGroup().getUsers());
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code showing that the back pointers have been set correctly.

```
[forum14844691.User@147ee929]
[forum14844691.User@685c53ff]
```

**FOR MORE INFORMATION**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-xmlinversereference-is-now-truly.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My use-case is as follows:  a group already exists in the database, and I want to add a user to the group.  When I try to add a user via REST and XML, MOXy ignores the group ID in the request (the child-to-parent relationship) and the user never gets associated with the group.  I have MOXy configured correctly,  evidenced by the cycle prevention when marshalling a list of groups with nested users.  How can I add a user to the group without MOXy ignoring the field?

Comment: @ptc - When Jackson unmarshals `{"name":"Jane Doe", "group":{"id":5}}` does `User` just have a skeleton instance of `Group` with only the `id` populated?

Comment: I'm not sure if the entire group is resolved or if it's just the skeleton.  I can check later tonight.  Jackson is forwarding enough info to Hibernate to store the group foreign key in my database.  I'll have more info later on.  Thanks!

Comment: @ptc - Also what does a message from `GroupEndpoint` look like?

Comment: It seems that the Group object returned from Jackson has only the information specified during the POST create user request, so in this case it only had an ID, no name.  I've added the relevant responses to the original question.  Let me know if you'd like to see anything else.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @ptc - What is the time frame for your app?  Your question has prompted an enhancement that we could implement in a few days.  If that doesn't fit your time frame I can help you with a workaround instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24475/discussion-between-ptc-and-blaise-doughan)

Comment: @ptc - I have updated my answer to reflect the new behaviour we have added to EclipseLink 2.5.0.